# Is there a Scheduler/Calendar JS Widget library?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I am looking for some JavaScript based component to be used as a course scheduler which would be a cross between Google Calendar and the login time. I do not know if the right term for this is *Course Scheduler* but I shall describe this in more detail here.

**Course Scheduler**
The widget would be used to enter date and times of a course, as an example if I run a programming course 3 days a week on Mon, Tue and Wed every 7:00 am to 9:00am, 2 hours every day from 1st September to 30th November. I could answer various questions and the course data would be displayed in the calendar. It would also allow for non pattern based timings where each week is different from the other week etc.

**Question**
So would I end up creating something from scratch? Would it be sensible to use Google Calendar API for this? I did a Google search for some widgets, but I believe I need better keywords, as I could not find anything close to what I am looking for. Any tips? Commercial libraries would also work for me. Thanks.

Comment: A small [calendar widget from YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/) could be used in the input/edit process. I'm not sure of any widgets that emulate a Google calendar week view style, which I believe you are looking for. An option could be to manage a calendar on Google calendar, and copy the html embed code found on the calendar settings.

Comment: Check out the Ext Scheduler, 100% javascript based on ExtJS. [http://www.bryntum.com](http://www.bryntum.com) Disclaimer, I'm the author of this component.

Comment: If you want something that looks like calendar, [www.web2cal.com](http://www.web2cal.com) is a good bet. Easy to use and looks intuitive to a naive user

Comment: You can try [Smart PHP Calendar](http://www.smartphpcalendar.com) also.
It's based on JavaScript (jQuery) and PHP. Note: This is a commercial application and I am the core developer of it.

Answer (score 16):

this could be what you're looking for:

[DHTMLxScheduler link](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml)

- It has day/week/month views
- It is free
- Data can be loaded in xml or iCal formats

You can populate the calendar using any server-side scripting language. If you wanted to,  you could just get your google calendar's xml data as per Mickey's example in the accepted post above, process it in your server-side language of choice and feed the calendar control with that data.

**EDIT**

I also found this project on Google code recently:

[JQuery Frontier Calendar](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-frontier-calendar/)

Comment: This one is nice and easy to go on with!

Comment: It is only free for GPL projects. You have to pay for using it otherwise

Answer (score 6):

try the following open source one. 
[wdCalendar](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/) is a jquery based google calendar clone. It cover most google calendar features.

```
* Day/week/month view provided.
* create/update/remove events by drag & drop.
* Easy way to integrate with database.
* All day event/more days event provided.
```