# JS Calendar Outlook control

Tags: javascript, outlook, calendar

can you share your experience about javascript outlook calendar like control

I have to add such a control to one project but don't have any experience at the moment

10x in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try this jquery weekly calendar

[New jQuery Weekly Calendar Plugin](http://www.redredred.com.au/new-jquery-weekly-calendar-plugin/)

Also check out [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173/is-there-a-scheduler-calendar-js-widget-library/969822#969822)